# In VS Code, how to dock Webview Developer Tools?

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, vscode-debugger

In VS Code, when you open the **Webview Developer Tools** window, it cannot be docked to the main Window.

There's no docking option in the Developer Tools menu:

[image]

And even if I use the command menu to let it dock, it doesn't work

[image]

Is there a way to dock it?

The normal Developer Tools can be docked.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you focus the debuggee? (That usually indicates it’s not docked currently). Also have you tried restoring defaults and reloading (from the dev tools settings)?

Comment: @soulshined Tried both and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103576, this is impossible, and VS Code team does not plan to support it either.

Comment: Oops, I misinterpreted the `webview` part.